# echo in an echo

Tags: php

I have the 2 following echos :

```
<?php echo $data->county; ?>
```

This one gives me datas like "florida", "california"... from the database

and

```
<?php echo lang(california); ?>
```

This one gives me a translation from a lang.php file, for example :

```
'california'   =>   'La californie'
```

I would like to place the $data->county in the lang echo, I tried the following with no success :

```
<?php echo lang(.$data->county.); ?>
```

What's the error ? Is it possible to echo in an echo ?

Comment: You're not "echo[ing] in an echo", you're just passing a string to a function.

Comment: Thanks, I just learnt basic php ;)

Comment: @minitech A last question I had, what if I want to add a word, for example "place" : 
    <?php echo lang($data->county+place); ?>  that should echo "californiaplace" , how should I writte it ?

Comment: @Jamescoo: For completeness’ sake — sorry, I didn’t see your message at the time: `<?php echo lang($data->county), 'place'; ?>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What made you think you needed the dots? Just pass it like any other argument:

```
<?php echo lang($data->county); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo lang($data->county); ?>
```

Lose the `.`s, they're for concatenating strings.  You're just passing a string variable.

Comment: @rocket What if I want to add a word, for example "place" : <?php echo lang($data->county+place); ?> that should echo "californiaplace" , how should I writte it ?

Comment: @Jamescoo: `<?php echo lang($data->county).'place'; ?>`